# Dynamic control click event not firing properly

Tags: c#, asp.net

I'm creating a next/previous function for my repeater using pageddatasource.  I added the link button control dynamically in my oninit using the following code.

```
LinkButton lnkNext = new LinkButton();
lnkNext.Text = "Next";
lnkNext.Click += new EventHandler(NextPage);

if (currentPage != objPagedDataSource.PageCount)
{
    pnlMain.Controls.Add(lnkNext);
}
```

So in my initial page_load, the next link comes up fine.  There are 5 pages in my objPagedDataSource.  currentPage variable is 1.

The "NextPage" event handler looks like this

```
public void NextPage(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (HttpContext.Current.Request.Cookies["PageNum"] == null)
    {
        HttpCookie cookie = new HttpCookie("PageNum");
        cookie.Value = "1";
    }
    else
    {
        HttpCookie cookie = HttpContext.Current.Request.Cookies["PageNum"];
        cookie.Value = (Convert.ToInt32(cookie.Value) + 1).ToString();
    }

    this.BindRepeater();
}
```

So I am incrementing the cookie I am using to track the page number and then rebinding the repeater.

Here is the main issue.  The first time I click Next, it works, it goes to Page 2 without any problems.  When on Page 2, I click Next, it goes back to Page 1.  Seems like the Next event is not wiring up properly.  Not sure why, any ideas?

Comment: When you are adding that control, are you doing it within an IsPostBack check?

    if (!IsPostBack) {
    
    }

Comment: Not doing an is postback check

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to ensure you're adding your dynamic control to the Page every postback. Dynamic controls often cause much pain - in this case it would probably be much easier to declare the "Next" LinkButton in the markup in the normal way, and just set `Visible = false` when it isn't required.

Comment: Thanks, this lead me down the right path about getting the controls setup on postback again, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

While you are loading user controls dynamically you must set ID property without ID property Events will not fire.This is My sample code to call user controls dynamically

```
private void LoadUserControl()
{
    string controlPath = LastLoadedControl;

    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(controlPath))
    {
        PlaceHolder1.Controls.Clear();
        UserControl uc = (UserControl)LoadControl(controlPath);
        uc.ID = "uc";  //Set ID Property here
        PlaceHolder1.Controls.Add(uc);
    }
}
```